# Deserialize and Filter Nested String in Gson Java

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to create an Application that can auto-create Memes. Every Meme from the API has different amounts of boxes (fields where the text can sit). Now I want to create an HTTP Request to get the fields for a specific meme ID.

The HTTP Request is working fine but I don't know how to deserialize and filter the received string.

Here is the JSON I want to Deserialize with GSON:

https://api.imgflip.com/get_memes

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

You need to get a JsonObject then in a JsonElement deserialize the "top-level-elements" and get it as a JsonArray. Then you can Loop through the array and get what you need.

```
    JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(content.toString(), JsonObject.class);
    JsonElement entry = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject("data").getAsJsonArray("memes");

    JsonArray entryArray = entry.getAsJsonArray();

    for (JsonElement element : entryArray) {
        JsonObject jsonObjectLoop = element.getAsJsonObject();

        if(jsonObjectLoop.get("id").getAsString().equals("14371066")) {
            System.out.println(jsonObjectLoop.get("box_count").getAsString());
        }
    }
```